# LPSolveAPI - how to find all solutions?

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, lpsolve

I am using LpSolveAPI package to solve a linear programming problem in R. This gives me one solution, but I would like to know if there are other solutions. Here is an example. Suppose I want to solve the following:

```
library(lpSolveAPI)

MyMatrix <- c(1,0,0,0,0,
              0,0,0,1,0,
              0,1,1,0,1,
              0,1,0,1,1,
              1,0,0,0,0,
              0,0,1,0,1)

MyMatrix <- matrix(MyMatrix,nrow=6,ncol=5,byrow=TRUE)

ObjFun=c(50,30,100,100,200)


lprec <- make.lp(0, 5)
set.objfn(lprec, ObjFun)
lp.control(lprec, sense="max")
set.type(lprec,c(1:5),"binary")


#not sure if this can be done easier (how to use the whole matrix MyMatrix?)
for (i in 1:6){
  add.constraint(lprec, MyMatrix[i, ], "<=", 1)
}
```

This gives the following problem:

[image]

We can solve this:

```
solve(lprec)
get.objective(lprec)
MySolution=get.variables(lprec)
```

And the solution will be (1 0 0 0 1). However, there is also another solution, namely (1,0,1,1,0). We can easily check this (first line checks the constraints, while the second line calculates the value of the objective function):

```
MyMatrix %*% MySolution
ObjFun %*% MySolution


AnotherSolution=c(1,0,1,1,0)

MyMatrix %*% AnotherSolution
ObjFun %*% AnotherSolution
```

Is there a way to get all solutions? Right now it only gives MySolution, while I would also like to get AnotherSolution. Is there a way to do that?

I know that in Matlab there is a function lcon2vert which can find vertices in a set defined by constraints - then in a "standard" LP problem one could evaluate the objective function in each vertex (since we know that we will have a corner solution). But here we also have a mixed integer solution.

Alternatively, if this is possible in other packages, I am ok if it is not LPsolveAPI. For example, the same problem can defined as:

```
library(magrittr)
library(ROI)
library(ompr)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
library(ompr.roi)

model <- MIPModel() %>%
  add_variable(solution[i], i=1:ncol(MyMatrix), type = 'binary') %>% 
  set_objective(sum_over(ObjFun[i] * solution[i], i=1:ncol(MyMatrix), sense = 'max')) %>% 
  add_constraint(sum_over(solution[i] * MyMatrix[j, i], i=1:ncol(MyMatrix)) <= 1, j=1:nrow(MyMatrix))

result <- solve_model(model, with_ROI("glpk", verbose = TRUE))

MyResult=result$solution
```

Here MyResult is also (1,0,0,0,1). Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get lpsolveAPI to return all possible solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55445759/how-to-get-lpsolveapi-to-return-all-possible-solutions)

Answer (score 0):

Only way is to add the current solution as a constraint and re-solve. At some point the problem will have a solution with a lower (or higher, depending on the direction of the objective function) objective value.